# Unable to update our Apps Marketplace listing. "update" button disabled

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Hi Google Admin SDK Devs,
We're having trouble updating our Google Apps Marketplace listing.  It's already published (and has been for a while with 5 stars and 50K+ users), but we'd like to update it with new screenshots and content.

When we go to the "Publish" tab, all of the fields are filled out but the "Update" button at the bottom remains disabled.

Can you help please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Marketplace question and not a programming question. We can't assist with your specific application or account in the Marketplace. Contact Marketplace support directly via the Google website for help.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for pointing that out.  I've switched the tag.  However, please note that I filed it here because google-admin-sdk is mentioned as a place to get help on this page: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The publish tab is currently used only for Gmail add-ons. You have to update the images in the corresponding Chrome Web Store listing and they will be sync in the G Suite Marketplace the next day.

Comment: Update here:  We updated the corresponding Chrome Web Store listing, but the changes haven't migrated.   Our Google Apps Marketplace listing is this one:  https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/apptoto/635317462637 .  Any ideas?

Comment: Not all images are migrated, the promotional media in particular are not, but the screenshots are.

Comment: @AlejandroTamalet how to edit Post tip text for editor add-ons? There is no such field in the Web Store Dashboard.

Comment: Not sure that is accurate anymore... It appears G Suite Marketplace is used for editor addons as well: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-overview

Comment: @Nathan is correct. The Chrome Web Store will be phased out for add-ons. As of today, I am also not sure how to Publish using G Suite Marketplace (I have a gray button and can't update my screenshots). In my case, it's a bundled add-on for Docs and Slides (it used to be an add-on that was only Docs, and started in 2014). The documentation for what to do as of today is at https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration#create_a_new_g_suite_marketplace_listing_for_an_editor_add-on but it's clearly in a state of flux.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator yes its very confusing... try to see if these instructions help: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gG0_EClZC4ztKHDT2yn8v9NmUh_-sqYFe9vGg6Snxgg/edit#heading=h.tfi8oizcsdl4

Comment: Wow @Nathan that is a super-helpful document! Especially the part about Publish being a cruel joke to cause us frustrations... However, I suspect that when CWS is completely deprecated for add-ons, Publish will make sense. Indeed my bundled add-ons got approved within 24 hours or so, and eventually made it to the marketplace. I'm now bummed that my 35K users went down to 0 in G Suite Marketplace, but I'm hoping they will come back.

Comment: FYI, the new GSM publishing flow, which no longer requires publishing to CWS is live. Regarding the users, the have been migrated too, but not the count yet. That will be done early next year.